# Get the API Key for use Rest API of Hotbit API

Tags: api, rest, pycrypto, cryptocurrency, cryptoapi

I'm going to make an application using REST API of Hotbit API, how is possible to get the API Key?
The REST API of Hotbit are located here: https://github.com/hotbitex/hotbit.io-api-docs/blob/master/readme_en.md

Comment: The document you refer to clearly states **Users may obtain their API permissions by visiting "Account Management->API Management" section of our website.**

Comment: @YuriGinsburg, Unfortunatelly the documention is wrong, there is no "Account Management" page and there is no "API Management" page. But API and a way to get keys defenitely exist, for example there is a recently developed library which supports official API keys amoung other auth methods: https://pypi.org/project/hotbit/ - on the page it is mentioned it is possible to get API keys, but not mentioned how.

Comment: @domenico do you found a way to get api keys?